# Give previous date as argument to shell script

Tags: shell-script, command-line, date

I need to execute the script by passing previous date as command line argument. It must be automated. So, how can i pass the previous date to the script?

For example:

```
sh processFile.sh previousdate previousdate
```

Comment: The correct answer may depend quite heavily on what type of Unix system this is for.

Answer (score 2):

With GNU `date`:

```
previousdate=$( date -d 'yesterday' +'%F' )
sh processFile.sh "$previousdate" "$previousdate"
```

With macOS `date`:

```
previousdate=$( date -j -v -1d +'%F' )
sh processFile.sh "$previousdate" "$previousdate"
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, got the answer. Posting that it would help someone.
It can be executed like this:

```
sh getDate.sh "$(date --date="-1 day" +%Y-%m-%d)" "$(date --date="-1 day" +%Y-%m-%d)"
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use this to get the previous day and pass it as an argument :

```
 date +%Y-%m-%d -d "1 day ago"
```

for more refer `man` page of `date` to even manipulate minutes and seconds.

Answer (score 0):

this will work:

```
sh processFile.sh "$(date +"%Y-%m-%d" -d "yesterday")"  "$(date +"%Y-%m-%d" -d "yesterday")"
```

Answer (score 0):

On [OpenBSD](//stackoverflow.com/a/15183128/1122270), [FreeBSD and MacOS](http://mdoc.su/f/date.1) with [BSD `date`](http://mdoc.su/-/date.1), plus illumos and other non-GNU systems:

```
YESTERDAY="$(date -r $(expr $(date +%s) - $(expr 60 \* 60 \* 24)) +%Y-%m-%d)"
sh processFile.sh $YESTERDAY $YESTERDAY
```

On GNU/Linux with `date` from GNU coreutils:

```
YESTERDAY="$(date -d-1day +%Y-%m-%d)"
sh processFile.sh $YESTERDAY $YESTERDAY
```